# GET in a For Loop does just one execution

Tags: javascript

Am trying to make a get request from javascript, with a function called geturl.
So if i prepare my querys and add it in to an array, and looping throw that executes just one request. 
how can do that without a for loop? perhaps doing something with the array?

```
for (var i=0; i<urls.length; i++)
        {
           url[i] = urls[i].value;
        }
geturl(url);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you posted any relevant code. This isn't your real loop, and you didn't post `geturl`...

Comment: Sorry i cant post code for geturl

Comment: ... but, it doesn't work well. Oh, and why are you against `for` loops again? They're really cool.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of this question. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a javascript framework you could do something along the lines of:

```
var collection;
$(urls).each(function(v){//add to collection});
geturl(collection);
```

[jQuery each documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: This would work, but I am failing to understand he even wants to get rid of the for loop. The $.each() method uses a for loop internally anyway.

Comment: I dont quite understand why the loop has to go either but its the only interpretation i could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a framework such as prototype or jQuery that give you an `each()` method to use on the array, *but* internally it would likely just use a for loop anyway, so there's not really much point to it.

Alternatively, if this is because you are using the for loop all over the place and want to have reusable code instead, why not attach a `buildUrl` method to your `urls` object (which loops internally, and returns your `url` array)

Or modify `geturl()` so it looks at the `.value` property of the argument rather than expecting each element of `url[]` to be a string, then pass `urls[]` in to `geturl` (eg `geturl(urls);` rather than passing in the array of string `url`

Answer (score 1):

A total stab in the dark, if the question is

> Why does geturl only get called once?

Then the answer could be:-

```
for (var i=0; i<urls.length; i++)
{
  url[i] = urls[i].value;
  geturl(url[i]);
}
```

However it is not apparent!

Comment: I tryed that several times it aborts and executes just one request

Comment: That would suggests that your problem lies in the implementation of geturl. Post the code!